# NoSuchFileException error while executing jar file

Tags: java, exception, null

I coded up a method which reads a text file, when I run it it works, but when I execute the jar, I get the NoSuchFileException error.
Here is my code:

```
private static final String textFile = "textFile.txt";

    public readText() {
    try {
        regex = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths
                .get(textFile)))
                .replaceAll("\\r", "").split("\n");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could someone point out where am I going wrong or what changes I'm supposed to make?

Comment: Is "textFile.txt" in your `jar` and if so where?

Comment: I checked the jar file by extracting it, there is no text file in it.

Comment: What is in the text file? Is it a resource supplied by you for the application to use? If so, it should be packaged inside the Jar and will **not be** be accessible as a `File`.

Comment: The text file contains words that I'm later using for comparison.

Comment: Make the program output the location of the text file when it runs - you’ll see why it’s giving you an error pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way:

```
try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(textFile);
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            content.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        regex = content.toString()
                .replaceAll("\\r", "").split("\n");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```